# How store full host name as variable in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I need to use one out of two hosts as a variable. I do have inventory_hostname_short of both but I need a full host as a variable. Currently, for testing I am using a hardcoded value. My playbook will run on both hosts at a same time so How I can identify and store as a variable.

```
host_1_full = 123.abc.de.com

host_2_full = 345.abc.de.com
```

above both are hosts and I do have

```
---
- name: Ansible Script 
  hosts: all
  
  vars:
    host1_short : '123'
    host2_short : '345'

  tasks:
    - name: set host
      set_fact:
        host1_full: "{{inventory_hostname}}"
      when: inventory_hostname_short == host1_short

    - name: print info
      debug:
        msg: "host - {{host1_full}}"

    - name: block1
      block:
      - name:running PS1 file
        win_shell: "script.ps1"
        register: host1_output
      
      when: inventory_hostname_short == host1_short  
      

    - name: block2
      block:
      
      - name: set host
        set_fact:
          IN_PARA: "{{ hostvars[host1_full]['host1_output']['stdout']}}"

      - name:running PS1 file
        win_shell: "main.ps1 -paramater {{ IN_PARA }}"
        register: output


      when: inventory_hostname_short == host2_short
```

SO to access any file from different host required full hostname. How can I get that full host name

Comment: Seems you want to use the FQDN of the hosts? If you have a standard naming system with FQDN in your infrastructure you can use `ansible_fqdn` variable.

Comment: @Seshadri C Thanks for your response. I just want to store one of the hosts names as variable. But the only particular which has host_1_short in that. Do you have any idea how can I store as a variable?

Comment: @SeshadriC I just update a question. It would be great If you can help ?

Answer (score 2):

Given the following `inventories/test_inventory.yml`

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    123.abc.de.com:
    345.abc.de.com:
```

ansible will provide the needed result in `inventory_hostname` automagically as demonstrated by the following `test.yml` playbook

```yaml
---
- name: print long and short inventory name
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: print info
      debug:
        msg: "Host full name is {{ inventory_hostname }}. Short name is {{ inventory_hostname_short }}"
```

which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/test_inventory.yml test.yml 

PLAY [print long and short inventory name] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [print info] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [345.abc.de.com] => {
    "msg": "Host full name is 345.abc.de.com. Short name is 345"
}
ok: [123.abc.de.com] => {
    "msg": "Host full name is 123.abc.de.com. Short name is 123"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
123.abc.de.com             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
345.abc.de.com             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks, Zeitounator but I want to store one of that {{ inventory_hostname }} as variable to use that in following two-block. As I do have both   {{ inventory_hostname_short }} I tried with when the condition to set_facts but then I am getting an error of undefined variable.

Comment: It is already stored in the varialbe `inventory_hostname` why do you need to copy it ?

Comment: I just update the question. I need to use a special variable so in that one of full hostname is required that why .!

Comment: Sorry but I absolutely don't understand what you are trying to do with your current code. But I if this what you need, what is the actual problem with that code? What is the expected result and what do you get instead?

Comment: Now you may get what I am trying say. I just updated the question. So in block2, I required the full hostname.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, the `ansible_hostname` and `ansible_fqdn` are automatic facts about hosts in your inventory. However, your requirement is a little unique. So we might have to apply a unique method to accomplish this. How about something like this?

Consider example inventory as below:

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    192.168.1.101:      # 123.abc.de.com
    192.168.1.102:      # 345.abc.de.com
```

We can have a play like this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    host1_short: 123
    host2_short: 345

  tasks:
  - command: "hostname -f"
    register: result

  - block:
    - set_fact:
        host1_full: "{{ result.stdout }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Host1 fullname: {{ host1_full }}"
    when: host1_short in result.stdout
```